# How to disable AppleThunderboltNHI.kext in macOS 13 Ventura

Tags: startup, thunderbolt, ventura, shutdown, kernel-extensions

I installed Ventura on my MacBook Pro 2014 15”. It has a [well-documented auto-shutdown problem](https://zh.ifixit.com/Answers/View/413521/Mid+2014+Retina+MBP+random+shutdowns) which requires disabling AppleThunderboltNHI.kext.

The method which worked in macOS 12.x now does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Allan: please leave this tagged [tag:boot] since "the famous auto-shutdown problem" means AppleThunderboltNHI.kext causes 2014 MBPs to bootloop. That's the symptom.

Comment: Is it a shutdown problem or a boot problem?  If it *causes* a shutdown that *then* boot loops, the problem isn’t the boot process.  Additionally, a tangential symptom, even a serious one, doesn’t mean it’s relevant.

Comment: I struggle to combine an auto-shutdown issue with a boot tag. Can you add a link which has more details for the shutdown issue?

Comment: @nohillside https://zh.ifixit.com/Answers/View/413521/Mid+2014+Retina+MBP+random+shutdowns

Comment: Thanks. This mentions random shutdowns, it doesn‘t describe a a bootlooping situation (where the system would crash/reboot during boot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way. OpenCore Legacy Patcher has an option to turn off Thunderbolt devices, Enable that and reinstall the patcher.
Now the world is in peace again.